# Sending array of string as a parameter to web service method using JAXRPC

Tags: java, web-services, axis, jax-rpc

I've got problem sending an array of string as parameter to a web service method, given in a specific wsdl. When am trying to send an array of strings, I get the following error.

### Error:

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.util.ArrayList &gt; 
class usdjws65.ArrayOfString)
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
            {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:SSLSPSD001

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.util.ArrayList -> class usdjws65.ArrayOfString)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at  org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
```

### Code written:

```
Call call1 = objService1.createCall(port1);
call1.setTargetEndpointAddress(targetEndPoint);
call1.addParameter("int_1", XMLType.XSD_INT, Integer.class,
                ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_1", QNAME_TYPE_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_2", QNAME_TYPE_STRING_ARRAY,
                java.lang.String[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_3", QNAME_TYPE_STRING_ARRAY,
                java.lang.String[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_4", QNAME_TYPE_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_5", QNAME_TYPE_STRING_ARRAY,
                java.lang.String[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_6", QNAME_TYPE_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call1.addParameter("String_7", QNAME_TYPE_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);

        // --- Done adding PARAM's

        String[] attrVals = { "description", "test from soapUI",
                "customer", ticketHandle, "type", "I" };
        String[] attributes = { "status", "ref_num" };

        Object[] params1 = { new Integer(sid), ticketHandle, attrVals, "",
                "cr_tpl:400005", attributes, "", "" };

        String res = null;
        try {
            call1.invoke(params1);
```

Thanks !!!!
-Aj

=========================================================

### **Update-1**:

I added a class named ArrayOfString with following code in it.
    protected java.lang.String[] string;

```
public ArrayOfString() {
}

public ArrayOfString(java.lang.String[] string) {
    this.string = string;
}

public java.lang.String[] getString() {
    return string;
}

public void setString(java.lang.String[] string) {
    this.string = string;
}
```

and thus did the following,
    ArrayOfString attrVals = new ArrayOfString();
    attrVals.setString(new String[] { "customer", "test from soapUI",
                        "customer", ticketHandle, "type", "I" });

Similarly, for attributes variable of type 'ArrayOfString'.

But now, I get the following error::

> AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class ArrayOfString in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@ef2c60
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class ArrayOfString in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@ef2c60
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1507)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:980)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.outputMultiRefs(SerializationContext.java:1055)
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPBody.outputImpl(SOAPBody.java:145)
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPEnvelope.outputImpl(SOAPEnvelope.java:478)
>       at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.output(MessageElement.java:1208)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2757)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)

---

### **Update-2:**

Here is an update on the problem that am facing. In the WSDL file, I found something like this,

```
complexType name="ArrayOfString"
sequence
element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" type="xsd:string" / 
/sequence
/complexType
```

Well, now that am meant to use this method,

```
 <element name="createRequest">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="sid" type="xsd:int" /> 
<element name="creatorHandle" type="xsd:string" /> 
<element name="attrVals" type="impl:ArrayOfString" /> 
<element name="propertyValues" type="impl:ArrayOfString" /> 
<element name="template" type="xsd:string" /> 
<element name="attributes" type="impl:ArrayOfString" /> 
<element name="newRequestHandle" type="xsd:string" /> 
<element name="newRequestNumber" type="xsd:string" /> 
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

Now, I tried sending the parameters 'attrVals','attibutes' like this

```
ArrayOfstring attrVals = new ArrayOfstring();
    ArrayOfstring attributes = new ArrayOfstring();
    attrVals.setString(new String[] { "customer", "test from soapUI",
            "customer", ticketHandle, "type", "I" });
    attributes.setString(new String[] { "status", "ref_num" });
```

Its throwing the following exception

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.tempuri.complex.data.arrays.xsd.ArrayOfstring in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@11e1e67
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException: No serializer found  for class org.tempuri.complex.data.arrays.xsd.ArrayOfstring in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@11e1e67
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1507)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:980)
```

Comment: Did you try WSDL2Java to generate client code with types? you can get the  ArrayOfString and its serializer from there.

Comment: I tried WSDL2JAVA CodeGen plugin for eclipse. I'd enetered all the required details but it gives me -'InvocationTargetException'.

Comment: did you check your web-service is up? it seams that either you use the wrong url or the web-service is down.

Comment: Well this problem has been solved. And I have updated the answer in the end below(after Update-2).                                         But the problem with WSDL2JAVA CodeGen is still persisting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above error has been solved. I simply registered the ArrayOfString class, String[] with the TypeRegistryMapping class.  Now, it doesn't throw the above serialize error.
Code edited is:

```
    ServiceFactory factory1 = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
    QName qnTick = new QName("http://soapinterop.org/xsd", "ArrayOfString");
    Service serviceTickReq = factory1.createService(qnTick);
    // Service serviceTickReq = new org.apache.axis.client.Service();
    TypeMappingRegistry tmr = (TypeMappingRegistry) serviceTickReq
            .getTypeMappingRegistry();
    TypeMapping tm = (TypeMapping) tmr.getDefaultTypeMapping();
    tm.register(ArrayOfString.class, qnTick, new BeanSerializerFactory(
            ArrayOfString.class, qnTick), new BeanDeserializerFactory(
            ArrayOfString.class, qnTick));

    TypeMappingRegistry tmr1 = (TypeMappingRegistry) serviceTickReq
            .getTypeMappingRegistry();
    TypeMapping tm1 = (TypeMapping) tmr1.getDefaultTypeMapping();
    tm1.register(String[].class, qnTick, new BeanSerializerFactory(
            String[].class, qnTick), new BeanDeserializerFactory(
            String[].class, qnTick));
```